# Convert Numbers.app spreadsheet to JSON document?

Tags: numbers

Is there a way to export a Numbers.app spreadsheet as a [JSON formatted](http://json.org/) file? I know I can do it manually but this will be used as data input to an iOS app and I'd like to have an automated way to do this to reduce errors.

Here's an image of the rough spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to export the data in the cells or the formulas in the cells? A spreadsheet can be represented as a two-dimensional array of data, do you want rows inside of columns or columns inside of rows in the JSON document? What if there is non-spreadsheet data like a picture or a graph? What do you want to happen with multiple sheets? Just export current sheet? Export all sheets? This can be done with AppleScript, but as you can see there are lots of open questions...

Comment: Ah, I should have said. No formulas, just text fields.its a two-dimensionalset.  Each row is a record. A record has 7 or 8 elements, represented stored in columns. I will update the question with a view of the data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you can directly convert a Numbers document to JSON. However, you can export a Numbers document to any number of formats, shown below.

[image: Exporting a document]

There are a bunch of converters for CSV->JSON. I found two online converters from a quick Google search: [Convert CSV](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) and [Mr. Data Converter](http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/).

This is not an ideal solution if you have a lot of these documents to convert, but I am sure that it will be easier to find effective CSV->JSON converters than Numbers->JSON converters.

Comment: thanks. that works for testing.. Do you know if you can run javascript? or applescripts in Numbers?

Comment: You can use AppleScript in conjunction with Numbers. http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/iwork/numbers/

Comment: Hmm. maybe I can write an applescript to function as an exporter.. I have a javascript.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That will not work if one of the columns have paragraphs containg `\n` that is also used to separate lines on the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I will hold out for a Numbers solution, but meanwhile, I have managed the process by using Google Sheets with [this Javascript](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2013/06/exporting-google-spreadsheet-as-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON is just a text file, in lieu of export, you could also just add a concatenate formula to each row the generates the JSON, like:

```
= CONCATENATE ("{","name:", A1, "somefield:", A2..., "}")
```

Or something like that...

Comment: How would this scale for bigger sheets?